# Invoking Stored Procedure from OracleJDBC giving exceptions

Tags: java, database, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to invoke stored procedure of Oracle using Oracle JDBC.

I am very new to Oracle and hence having difficulty figuring out how to invoke the SP and get the proper output.

**The Stored procedure below is supposed to give me just 4 outputs with no input.**

Code snippet is :

```
cStmt=connection.prepareCall(" {call userName.user(?)}");               
                    cStmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

                    cStmt.executeUpdate();                  

                    rst = (ResultSet) cStmt.getObject(1);
                    while (rst.next()) {
                        int id = rst.getInt(1);
                        int Id1=rst.getInt(2);
                        String accoutNum=rst.getString(3);
                        String accountName=rst.getString(4);
                        System.out.println("valeus");
                        System.out.println(id);
                        System.out.println(Id1);
                        System.out.println(accoutNum);
                        System.out.println(accountName);
                    }
```

Now running this code is giving me following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'user'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:505)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:223)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:204)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1041)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1328)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3593)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3674)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.executeUpdate(OracleCallableStatement.java:4780)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
        at demo.Oracle.main(Oracle.java:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

I am sure there's a definite problem with the syntax. I googled a lot but I am not able to find the concrete solution..

Can someone please guide me.. JDBC jar version is **6.0**

the Header of procedure is :

```
create or replace
procedure user is 
cursor user_cursor is select * from user_master;
v_rec_user user_cursor%rowtype;
```

Comment: could you please post the header of the stored procedure?

Comment: @StefanBeike Please see the edit. Added header at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your procedure definition has no parameter; the way you're calling it you're expecting it to have an OUT parameter of type [`sys_refcursor`, or a schema-level cursor type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_variable.htm).

I think you want something like this:

```
create or replace procedure user(result out sys_refcursor) is
begin
    open result for
        select * from user_master;
end;
/
```

But as you've only shown the start it isn't clear what you're using `v_rec_cursor` for.

(Also, `user` is not a good name for the procedure as it's a reserved word; maybe something like `get_users` would be better?)

---

Small Java program to call that procedure and print the results; this compiles and runs for me (with `*` replaced with real DB connection details):

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

public final class DBTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws SQLException
    {
        OracleDataSource datasource;
        Connection conn = null;
        CallableStatement cStmt = null;
        ResultSet rSet = null;

        try
        {
            datasource = new OracleDataSource();
            String jdbcURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:*/*@*:1521:*";
            datasource.setURL(jdbcURL);
            conn = datasource.getConnection();
            cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call get_user(?) }");
            cStmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            cStmt.execute();
            rSet = (ResultSet) cStmt.getObject(1);
            while (rSet.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rSet.getInt(1)
                    + ":" + rSet.getInt(2)
                    + ":" + rSet.getString(3)
                    + ":" + rSet.getString(4));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rSet != null)
            {
                rSet.close();
            }
            if (cStmt != null)
            {
                cStmt.close();
            }
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did what you suggested. Atleast the above mentioned error is not coming. However the resultset is null.I am getting null pointer exception when I am trying to do cStmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);   I think I am close.Can you please help.

Comment: @AngelsandDemons - an NPE from that statement is nothing to do with the result set, you haven't got that fair. Odd for `cStmt` to be null, can you verify that in your code? Other thoughts... you might want to use `execute()` instead of `executeUpdate()`, and `getCursor()` instead of `getObject()`, but again you don't seem to be reaching those.

Comment: i am using execute() only. cStmt is not null. However I could not udnerstand where do you want me to write getCursor(). cStmt.getCursor() is undefined. Can you please guide me with this.

Comment: @AngelsandDemons - OK, I usually use an `OracleCallableStatment`, which has `getCursor`; `getObject` is fine if you're using `CallableStatement`. So if `cStmt` isn't null, where is the NPE happening?

Comment: @AngelsandDemons - I added a simple Java program that calls your procedure. I'm not sure what you're doing differently.